# reading file unknown format in C

Tags: c

I need some help with this exercise in `C language`.

I would like to know how do I read data from a file that I don't know it's format.

-The file will contain int(`1-999`) and char: "`OL`"=overloaded, "`ND`"=noData, "`LB`"=lowBattery.

Example:

> My_file.txt

Can be made like this:

```
25
764
OL
ND
34
LB
624
235
ND
........
```

Or like this:

```
534 ND 356 LB LB 234 765 123 ND ND......
235 976 LB 156 ND......
```

I know that this:

```
   FILE *f;
    char str1;
    f=fopen(filename,"r");
    str1=fgetc(f); 
    while(str1 != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c",str1);
        str1=fgetc(f);
    }
   fclose(f);
```

can read the file until `EOF`. But I can't use it because i need to assign those values to some int or chars...(what if i use `enum`?)

I am sure that I can't use `fscanf`. But the real question is: How to I read the file, and how to I assign those values to a `struct` or something... 
So then i can use them for operations(like sum and more).

Thank you very much guys...

Comment: Why not use fscanf and test that you were able to store the result as an integer?

Comment: `fscanf` is like this: `fscanf(filename, " %... %... %... %...", w,x,y,z);`  I don't know what the file can contain, i only know that can be an **int** or **char**. I was thinking about using `fscanf(fname, "%c", characters); `and store the numbers as `char` but if the number is **>255** How will it be stored in a char? And what if the file is like in _option 2_.     Is there any other way to use `fscanf`? :)

Comment: If you don't care about the difference between spaces and line breaks, fscanf is the right tool -- `fscanf("%s",`... will read a single 'item' or `fscanf("%d",`... will read an number (and will return 0 if the next thing is not a number, so you can then use `"%s"` to read it.)

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know it's format

Hmm .. it seems to me that You know the format exactly:

> The file will contain int(1-999) and char: "OL"=overloaded, "ND"=noData, "LB"=lowBattery

Your file contains a whitespace separated sequence of tokens, each of which is either OL, ND, LB or an integer in the specified range.

So to parse that file read one character at a time. Whitespace? Ignore and continue with the next. A digit? Now should come up to 2 more digits. Read them and convert to an integer. `'O'`, `'N'` or `'L'`? Look for the next character to be the correct one. Everything else? Parse error!

To save each token create a structure like:

```
struct Token
{
  enum
  {   TokenOverLoad
    , TokenNoData
    , TokenLowBattery
    , TokenData
  } kind;
  short data; // only if kind == TokenData
};
```

Then store these in either a list or dynamic array during parsing. Afterwards You can iterate over that list/array to implement any required functions like sum ...

Answer (score 0):

I asked a friend. He said that I can use `fscanf`.

I only need to define a `struct` with characters.

With `fscanf` I will read `%s` and add them to the `char char_name[20];`

If I want, i can use `atoi/atof` for the numbers or `strcmp` for the chars.

If anybody knows another easiest solution. Please answer :)
Soon i will post the code, working on it:)